# jQuery/Javascript - Delay the execution of a function until another one is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, delay

I'm trying to load a php page into an element and then apply a slider to the content loaded.
The problem is the content takes a few seconds to load after the function is executed and the slider already begins to work.
I'm trying to somehow delay the execution of the slider function until the php embedding function is done.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ajaxpage("products.php?type=featured&order=salesNumber", "featuredArea");
});

$(document).ready(setTimeout(function () {
    $(".productsArea").easySliderProducts({
        nextText: "Next",
        prevText: "Previous"
    });
    document.getElementById("outputHere").innerHTML = $(".page ul#featuredArea li").length;
    $(".page").easySlider({
        s: $(".page ul#featuredArea li").length,
        auto: true,
        continuous: false,
        nextId: "featNextArrow",
        nextText: "",
        prevId: "featPrevArrow",
        prevText: "",
        pause: 7500
    });
}, 1000));
```

I separated both in order to use the setTimeout function.
It works for me, but the result may be different for other people.
I was wondering if it's possible to wait until the ajaxpage function is done loading the page and THEN continue with the code?

AjaxPage code: http://pastebin.com/XWa0jD77
easySlider1.7 code: http://pastebin.com/CzK8BzfL

I thought about calling the slider from within the embedded page, though that won't work.

Comment: The settimeout as an argument to document.ready doesn't do antyhing, you might aswell remove the document.ready there.

Comment: the AjaxPage snippet is missing a VERY important piece of functionality, i suggest not using it and just using jQuery for your ajax needs. (it doesn't support Deferred objects and it doesn't allow you to assign a callback to it being done or failing)

Comment: Yeah, just replace your ajaxpage function with jQuery's .load(), you can pass a callback there to be run only when the request is completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are already using jquery i suggest you throw away your ajaxpage function and use [$jQuery.load();](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead.

As you can see in the jquery doc`s, load() comes with a callback function which does exactly what you need.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's way faster than ajaxpage and works great! So easy! :) Thank god for jQuery!